# Only Accept Numbers with Decimal in a Input Using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, decimal

How to only allow decimals numbers in a Input Ej:

```
12.00,
12.44,
00.34
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Do you mean at validation (of some kind) or do you mean not even letting the key presses register in the input?

Comment: Yes!, I want Validate an input for only set numbers with decimals :), sorry for my bad english

Comment: You'll want to look into attaching a handler for an onkeydown event.  You'll need to check in the event object to see what the actual key pressed was, and then you can either return false or true to allow the event to continue or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
var isFloat = function(n) {
 return n % 1 !== 0;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/iwitep/edit

So you could do:

```
if(isFloat(n)){
  //Do something
}
else{
  //Give an error
}
```